# Rust can't find crate

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I'm trying to create a module in Rust and then use it from a different file. This is my file structure:

```
matthias@X1:~/projects/bitter-oyster$ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── Readme.md
├── src
│   ├── liblib.rlib
│   ├── lib.rs
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── main.rs~
│   └── plot
│       ├── line.rs
│       └── mod.rs
└── target
    └── debug
        ├── bitter_oyster.d
        ├── build
        ├── deps
        ├── examples
        ├── libbitter_oyster.rlib
        └── native

8 directories, 11 files
```

This is Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "bitter-oyster"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["matthias"]

[dependencies]
```

This is main.rs:

```
extern crate plot;

fn main() {
    println!("----");
    plot::line::test();
}
```

This is lib.rs:

```
mod plot;
```

this is plot/mod.rs

```
mod line;
```

and this is plot/line.rs

```
pub fn test(){
    println!("Here line");
}
```

When I try to compile my program using: `cargo run` I get:

```
   Compiling bitter-oyster v0.1.0 (file:///home/matthias/projects/bitter-oyster)
/home/matthias/projects/bitter-oyster/src/main.rs:1:1: 1:19 error: can't find crate for `plot` [E0463]
/home/matthias/projects/bitter-oyster/src/main.rs:1 extern crate plot;
```

How do I compile my program? As far as I can tell from online documentations this should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have the following problems:

1. you have to use `extern crate bitter_oyster;` in `main.rs`, because the produced binary **uses** your crate, the binary is not a part of it.
2. Also, call `bitter_oyster::plot::line::test();` in `main.rs` instead of `plot::line::test();`. `plot` is a module in the `bitter_oyster` crate, such as `line`. You are referring to the `test` function with its fully qualified name.
3. Make sure, that every module is exported in the fully qualified name. You can make a module public with the `pub` keyword, like `pub mod plot;`

You can find more information about Rust's module system here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html

A working copy of your module structure is as follows:

src/main.rs:

```
extern crate bitter_oyster;

fn main() {
    println!("----");
    bitter_oyster::plot::line::test();
}
```

src/lib.rs:

```
pub mod plot;
```

src/plot/mod.rs:

```
pub mod line;
```

src/plot/line.rs :

```
pub fn test(){
    println!("Here line");
}
```

Answer (score 34):

To add to the given answers, a library compiled as a `cdylib` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html)) can generate this error when you try to reference it in another project. I solved it by separating the code I wished to reuse in a regular `lib` project.

Comment: This is the case for example when using `PY03` which required `cdylib`. To fix this I set `crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]` which means the library worked for both python compiling and using the crate in other rust libraries.

Answer (score 29):

If you see this error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `PACKAGE`
  |
1 | extern crate PACKAGE;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

it could be that you haven't added the desired crate to the dependencies list in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
PACKAGE = "1.2.3"
```

*See [specifying dependencies in the Cargo docs](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html).*

Comment: Note: googling this error sends you here, so I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: How does one determine which version of a crate to specify? Is there always a place to look for release notes that would give a clue?

Comment: @JamesJones usually what it says on crates.io will be what you want (the latest) https://crates.io/crates/serde, you can also see dependencies etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when I had imported my crate in [dev-dependencies] instead of [dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you don't enable certain "feature flags" for specific crates. Unfortunately, these feature flags can sometimes be undocumented. When feature flags are missing when required, they show the same error ("Can't find crate")

I was using `diesel`, and was trying to use `BigInteger`:

### Wrong

```yaml
diesel = { version = "2.0.3", features = ["postgres", "chrono", "r2d2", "serde_json", "biginteger"] }
```

### Correct:

```yaml
diesel = { version = "2.0.3", features = ["postgres", "chrono", "r2d2", "serde_json", "numeric"] }
```